# Принцип окончаний

Tags: орфография

"Ножниц**ы**", но "пяльц**а**" - почему так? Слова, вроде, однотипные, но окончания разные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пяльц**ы**, конечно. 
Но и "однотипность" вы определили неправильно. К формам множественного на -а тяготеют слова мужского рода с ударением на предпоследнем слоге. Ножницы - во-первых, женского (по форме родительного падежа множественного числа) и, во-вторых, с ударением на первом слоге.

Ещё такую форму регулярно имеют слова среднего рода, уже вне зависимости от места ударения, но это тоже не наш случай.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то не пяльц**а**, а пяльц**ы** (Полный орфографический словарь русского языка под ред. В.В. Лопатина)